# can we mock private , static method in java 11 without powermock since powermock not support java 11

Tags: java, powermock

I have legacy code and i am using power mock for mocking the private and static method but power mock does not support java 11. I want to use some other tools or any workaround to mock the private and static method in my project. i am aware that testing of the private method is bad Unit testing.
I have tried the reflection way of writing the Unit test case in place of powermock but I did not have much success on that.I heard of JMockito as the other option but due to some issue, we can not go for JMockito.
Please suggest if any other feasible solution I can use to mock this ?

Comment: Mockito can now do this see https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods for more details

Comment: Thanks, @JamesMudd .what about the private method?